# Access value returned from outer filter() funciton inside fetch

Tags: javascript, function, filter, scope, fetch

I want to access the value returned from an outer function inside the property of fetch.
The value is being logged out but I need to get the value inside fetch in the 'title' property. Please excuse me if it is an irrelevant question, I am new to this. Need a solution or an alternative please.

```
button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
function editTodo(e) {
  function filterID() {
    Array.from(todoItem).filter((item) => {
      if (item.getAttribute('id') == todoID) {
        console.log(item.innerHTML);
        return item.innerHTML;
      }
    });
  }      //<<value is being logged out

  fetch(`${url}/${id}`, {
    method: 'PATCH',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ 
      title: filterID(),   //<<need to access here
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => {
        setMessage('Updated');
        return res.json();
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
})
```

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the array that `filter` creates, so the `return item.innerHTML;` is pointless -- the value returned is put in the array you never use. (Traditional functions never do implicit `return`, and there's no `return` in your `filterID` function, just the `filter` callback.) It's not clear at all to me that you need or want `filter`. What is `todoItem`?

Comment: It is an array of html elements and  I am returning the innerHTML of the element which matches the if condition.. Is there a way I can refine it so that the value can be accessible outside?

Comment: You never call `editTodo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple of issues:

- You aren't doing anything with the array that `filter` creates, so the `return item.innerHTML;` doesn't do anything — the value returned is put in the array you never use. (Traditional functions never do implicit `return`, and there's no `return` in your `filterID` function, just the `filter` callback.)
- You never call `editTodo`.
- It sounds from the comments like you have a collection/list of HTML elements and you're trying to find the one that matches `todoID` and use its `innerHTML` in the fetch call. If so, that would be a [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) operation rather than a [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) operation.

See comments:

```
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Where is `editTodo` used??
    function editTodo(e) {
        // `todoItem` really should be plural if it"s a collection/list/array
        // Use `find` to find the matching `todo`, and then use `innerHTML` on it
        const todo = Array.from(todoItem).find((item) => item.getAttribute("id") === todoID);
        if (!todo) {
            return; // Not found
        }

        fetch(`${url}/${id}`, {
            method: "PATCH",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                title: todo.innerHTML, // ***
            }),
        })
            .then((res) => {
                setMessage("Updated");
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    }
});
```

Or with a `for-of` loop on `todoItem` since both `NodeList` (from `querySelectorAll`) and `HTMLCollection` (from `getElementsByXYZ` methods) are iterable (like arrays are):

```
button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    // Where is `editTodo` used??
    function editTodo(e) {
        // `todoItem` really should be plural if it"s a collection/list/array
        // Use `find` to find the matching `todo`, and then use `innerHTML` on it
        let todo = null;
        for (const item of todoItem) {
            if (item.getAttribute("id") === todoID) {
                todo = item;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!todo) {
            return; // Not found
        }

        // ...same otherwise...
    }
});
```